# Enabling filegroup in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream, filegroup

I have enabled filestream in SQL Server configuration manager and also restarted SQL Server, but when I want to enable file group for my database the option is locked for me

[image]

SSMS database properties:

Comment: Did you also configure filestream as specified [in steps 11-13 in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?view=sql-server-ver15#enabling)?

Comment: yes I did but there is still these problem